# How to configure Azure Virtual Machine Agent in Win 10 x86 bit VM?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to configure azure virtual machine agent in Windows 10 x86 bit vm. But I am not able to do. By default Azure virtual machine agent is supported in Windows 10 x64 bit VMs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot get that. And just as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#manual-installation) said, you have configured Azure Virtual Machine Agent into `64-bit` environment.  Other than that, you have no other way.